# Unexpected Token equal symbol in execute anonymous window

Tags: execute-anonymous

I am facing an unexpected token error when I am trying to insert a record through execute anonymous window.

```
list<location_tracing__c> newRecs = new list<location_tracing__c>();
location_tracing__c loc1 = new location_tracing__c(Name = 'Bangalore');
loc1.PersonId__c = 'Rajeswari';
loc1.Visit_date__c = 2021-04-30;
loc1.location__c = 'Bangalore Cantonment';
newRecs.add(loc1);
```

when I click on execute button, I am getting the error like below

> Line: 4, Column: 20
> Unexpected token '='.

i.e on the visit_date__c line.

I am unable to get any clue why this error happens, even though everything seems to be okay to the best of my analysis.  Please some one guide me..

Answer (score 0):

Date values must use the appropriate [`Date`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_date.htm)`.newInstance` method:

```
list<location_tracing__c> newRecs = new list<location_tracing__c>();
location_tracing__c loc1 = new location_tracing__c(Name = 'Bangalore');
loc1.PersonId__c = 'Rajeswari';
loc1.Visit_date__c = Date.newInstance(2021,4,30);
loc1.location__c = 'Bangalore Cantonment';
newRecs.add(loc1);
```

In this case, the error is a red herring because the compiler misinterpreted what you were attempting to accomplish.

You can't write just 2021-04-30, as the compiler would interpret that as "subtract 4 from 2021, then subtract 30 from that", which ends up being a number, not a date you can assign.

I'm not entirely sure why it gave you that error instead of something like "cannot assign Integer to Date", though.